# Is it redundant to set your primary key as a unique key?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, mysql-workbench, unique-constraint

I'm putting tables together in MySQL workbench and I'm currently ticking my primary keys to also be uniquely indexed. Is this a redundant configuration?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, like in most other DBMS, each primary key is already indexed, so it is not necessary to ask for explicit indexing.

Comment: Workbench is telling me that my primary key is needed to be uniquely index for it to be a foreign key, too. It won't let me uncheck it and apply without it on.

Comment: What exact error do you get? Workbench allows to mark a column as PK, UQ or both. If a column is marked as PK, it would not force you to make it as UQ, too. (unless you have composite keys, is that the case)?

Comment: @adampski, perhaps you should look at this question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45424/prevent-mysql-workbench-to-add-index-for-foreignkey-constraint-when-it-is-first

Comment: Answer to ur question is Yes. It is redundant. Primary key is both unique and indexed so u don't need to make it unique. If you cannot achieve this from workbench, it is better to change ur question with providing screenshot and table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Primary key is unique by nature.